# How do I use "after_run" in minitest?

Tags: ruby, minitest

How on earth do I use the [`after_run`](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest.rb#L66) class function to run some code after all my tests are done? All my attempts raise `NoMethodError`:

```
class MyTest < Minitest::Test
  after_run {
    puts "After run!"
  }
end

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MyTest < Minitest::Test
  self.after_run {
    puts "After run!"
  }
end

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MyTest < Minitest::Test
end

MyTest.after_run {
  puts "After run!"
}
```

Using Minitest 5.2.2

Comment: `Minitest.after_run { p $debugging_info }` Put it to test_helper.rb

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Presumably that would run after *every* test suite..?

Comment: Nope, after whole suite is done running.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I see... This isn't useful at all for me then :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assumed `after_run` would run after all the tests in the class, but as [Sergio Tulentsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125816/sergio-tulentsev) pointed out, it runs after the whole test suite is complete. For the sake of completeness, this is how it's used:

```
Minitest.after_run {
  puts "The whole test suite is complete"
}
```